# About the YouTube video "The Riemann Hypothesis, Explained"

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

About the video [The Riemann Hypothesis, Explained](https://youtu.be/zlm1aajH6gY?t=658) at 658 secs and on:

1. What are the meanings of the curves (and their analytic forms) that create the spiral or heart shapes and that keep hitting the zeta zeros several times?
2. What do these mean to have the curves keep hitting the zeta zeros **multiple say N times**?
   What is the meaning of this N? if hitting N times? (or can the N be bounded finite or be infinite?)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recognize the spiral as being the curve parametrized by $\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)$ for $t$ in some finite interval $[0,T]$; the spiral is growing larger by making $T$ larger. The value $\zeta(\frac{1}{2})=1.46035...$ is the leftmost point on the spiral in the video, where it starts. If you look closely, the "critical line" $\mathrm{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}$ (the vertical orange line halfway between $0$ and $1$) is the one that turns into the spiral.

In general, the straight lines of the grid moments before are a "before" picture, and the collection of curves moments later are the "after" picture. That is, the curves are the images of $\zeta$ applied to the original straight lines. The dark teal curves are those that can be obtained using the original series definition of $\zeta$, while the orange ones are those that can only be obtained by using analytic continuation to extend the domain of $\zeta$.

(I am unsure but very curious how they smoothly transitioned the lines into curves.)

Every time the spiral hits the origin is a zero of the zeta function. So the multiplicity with which the spiral intersects the origin is the number of zeros $\zeta$ has on the critical line with imaginary part restricted to the interval $[0,T]$. As $T$ grows larger, this number will keep growing, forever.

Comment: many thanks voted up

Comment: +1, Is there a simple way to understand the trivial zeros at the x<0 axis for x=-2,-4,-6, in the similar way - how the $f(z)$ as $z=x<0$ hits the zeros? and why the even x=-2,-4,-6 hit zeros?

Comment: ALSO HOW much do we know the **analytic form** of this curve (1) (1/2+)   and (2) $(x<0)$  ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3978898/141334

Comment: @anniemarieheart There are tricks you can do to nonrigorously regularize the series for small negative even numbers. You can prove the negative even numbers are zeros using the functional equation for $\zeta$ along with the poles of the gamma function $\Gamma$. What exactly do you mean by analytic form of $\zeta$ by the way? It already has an explicit formula on the right half, which yields an explicit formula on the left half using the functional equation. Your other question you linked is answered in the comments.